# XAMPP Apache not starting?

Tags: apache, web, xampp, webserver

When I run the XAMPP control panel, and click start on the Apache button, it says "Attempting to start Apache service", but nothing happens. I have tried starting up Apache multiple times, but it appears stuck in "Attempting to start Apache service". There is never an error message. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to start apache from outside. I mean outside from XAMPP.

Comment: try running xampp as an administrator.

Comment: yeah, so i just tried running xampp as administrator, but it still seems stuck on attempting to start. Is there anything else I can try?